# I need help on js and jquery form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

i have problem with this query when  i fill my email box with correct email it can validate and then ask me correct email and when i change my email box to empty it shows me correct email address. let check this http://www.icodecrew.com/register

```
             if(email == "") {
        $("span.val_email").html("Please Enter Your Correct Email-ID.").addClass('validate');
        validation_holder = 1;
    } else { 
        if(!email_regex.test(email)){ // if invalid email
            $("span.val_email").html("Invalid Email!").addClass('validate');
            validation_holder = 1;
        } else {
  $("span.val_email").html("");

                 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#email").change(function(){

             $("span.val_email").html("<img src='spinner.gif' /> Please wait until we check...");


        var email=$("#email").val();

          $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"includes/checkemail.php",
                data:"email="+email,
                    success:function(data){
                    if(data==0){
                        $("span.val_email").html("<img src='accept.png' title='available' />");
                    }
                    else{
                        $("span.val_email").html("<img src='error.png' /> E-Mail is Already registered");
                    }
                }
             });

        });

     }); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: order of operations? you assign `email` a value after you perform the `if` statement, when you should assign it as the first thing.

Comment: Why is there a `$(document).ready(function(){` nested in there? document.ready should wrap any and all jquery code that access DOM elements, also please fix the indentation in your question code

Comment: I tried to format that code for you, but it would be impossible without guessing the missing bits.

Comment: `$(document).ready` should generally be at the very beginning of your code; it tells jQuery to wait till the document is ready to run that code, so it doesn't make sense to use it in response to an event after the page is already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @PlantTheldea in the comments to your question, your order of operations is severely broken. Having read through your code, this is the closest I can come to what I believe you want. It is **UNTESTED** and *serves only to help you determine the order in which your steps should be executed*:

```
$(function () {
    var email_input = $('#email');

    email_input.change(function () {
        var status_display = $('span.val_email'),
            email = email_input.val();

        if (email === '') {
            status_display
                .html('Please Enter Your Correct Email-ID.')
                .addClass('validate');

            validation_holder = 1;
        } else { 
            if (!email_regex.test(email)) {
                status_display
                    .html('Invalid Email!')
                    .addClass('validate');

                validation_holder = 1;
            } else {
                status_display
                    .html('<img src="spinner.gif" /> Please wait until we check...')
                    .removeClass('validate');

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'includes/checkemail.php',
                    data: {
                        email: email
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data == 0){
                            status_display.html('<img src="accept.png" title="available" />');
                        } else {
                            status_display.html('<img src="error.png" /> E-Mail is Already registered');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```